# nhibernate log to stdout

Tags: c#, nhibernate, c#-4.0

I am using Nhibernate 3.3 and I have set up the configuration so that it should log SQL, etc. In the past (NH 2.2+) I have set stdout to a StreamWriter like so:

```
  string nhLoggerPath = "...path...";
  Logger = new StreamWriter(nhLogPath, false, Encoding.UTF8);
  Console.SetOut(Logger);
```

And everything was working just fine.  Now with version 3.3, I get everything in my log file as before, EXCEPT for the sql that Nhibernate is supposed to be logging.  What has changed, or what do I need to do to get everything working again?

p.s. I am not using log4net (obviously) and I don't care to either.

Here is how I am setting up the logging....

```
...
db.ConnectionString = @"myConnectionString";
db.LogSqlInConsole = true;
db.LogFormattedSql = true;
...
```

Answer (score -1):

how do you setup logging sql? NH 2.x used log4net exclusivly, NH3.x has an internal logger implementation which defaults to log4net if present or nologging when not present. You probably did not configure it to log to console.